# Multidimensional array multiplication in R

Tags: r, multidimensional-array

I would like to perform some complex multidimensional array multiplication where I *multiply over specific margins* of arrays.

Consider this example, where I have prevalence of a grouping feature (A and B) by some margins of a population:

```
# setup data

random=runif(4)

group.prevalence <- aperm (array(c(random,1-random),
                  dim=c(2,2,2), 
                  dimnames=list(age=c("young","old"),
                                gender=c("male","female"),
                                group=c("A","B"))) , c(3,1,2) )

group.prevalence 
# A + B = 1
```

Suppose now that I have a population of interest …

```
population <- round(array(runif(4, min=100,max=200) %o% c(1,1*(1+random[1]),1*(1+random[1])^2), 
                          dim=c(2,2,3), dimnames=list(age=c("young","old"),
                                                      gender=c("male","female"),
                                                      year=c("year1","year2","year3"))))

population
```

… for which I would like to calculate the prevalence of "A" and "B".

The bad solution would be to fill it all in a loop:

```
# bad solution
grouped.population <- array(NA, dim=c(2,2,2,3), 
                            dimnames=list(group=c("A","B"),
                                          age=c("young","old"),
                                          gender=c("male","female"),
                                          year=c("year1","year2","year3")))

for (group in c("A","B"))
  for(gender in c("male","female"))
    for (age in c("young","old")) 
      grouped.population[group,age,gender,] <- group.prevalence[group,age,gender] * population[age,gender,]
```

But I suppose that some sort of apply could come in handy, possibly plyr's aaply, because the result's dimensions should be retained. I have tried:

```
library(plyr)
aaply(population, c(1,2), function(x) x * group.prevalence)
# too many dimensions
```

I welcome any suggestions.

Comment: Please correct the title of your question, it is unclear and not showing what you actually want to ask

Answer (score 1):

For your particular case, you can compute:

```
out <- rep(group.prevalence, times=last(dim(population))) * 
       rep(population, each=first(dim(group.prevalence)))
```

and then you can set the dimensions of this `array`:

```
array(out, dim=c(2,2,2,3), 
      dimnames=list(group=c("A","B"),
                    age=c("young","old"),
                    gender=c("male","female"),
                    year=c("year1","year2","year3")))
```

The key is to **align** the dimensions of the two arrays via **transposition** of dimensions and **expansion/replication** to fill the missing dimensions that are in the other array. In general, the procedure is:

1. Identify the *intersecting* dimensions. Here, it is `(age,gender)`.
2. For the left hand side argument of the multiply, `group.prevalence`, permute the dimensions (using `aperm`) so that all the non-intersecting dimensions (i.e., `group`) are first. Then, replicate that array `N` times (using `times`) where `N` is the size of the non-intersecting dimensions (i.e., `year`) of the right hand side argument, `population`.
3. For the right hand side argument of the multiply, `population`, permute the dimensions so that all the non-intersecting dimensions (i.e., `year`) are last. Then, replicate each element of the array `M` times (using `each`) where `M` is the size of the non-intersecting dimensions (i.e., `group`) of the left hand side argument, `group.prevalence`.
4. Then just (array) multiply, which is vectorized and fast.
5. The *joint* dimensions of the result is simply the non-intersecting dimensions of the left hand side argument, followed by the intersecting dimensions, followed by the non-intersecting dimensions of the right hand side (i.e., `(group, age, gender, year)`). You can then permute these dimensions as necessary in the output to get what you want.

As a check:

```
# bad solution
grouped.population <- array(NA, dim=c(2,2,2,3), 
                            dimnames=list(group=c("A","B"),
                                          age=c("young","old"),
                                          gender=c("male","female"),
                                          year=c("year1","year2","year3")))

for (group in c("A","B"))
  for(gender in c("male","female"))
    for (age in c("young","old")) 
      grouped.population[group,age,gender,] <- group.prevalence[group,age,gender] * population[age,gender,]

# another approach
grouped.population2 <- array(rep(group.prevalence, times=last(dim(population))) * 
                             rep(population, each=first(dim(group.prevalence))), 
                             dim=c(2,2,2,3), 
                             dimnames=list(group=c("A","B"),
                                           age=c("young","old"),
                                           gender=c("male","female"),
                                           year=c("year1","year2","year3")))

# check
all.equal(grouped.population,grouped.population2)
##[1] TRUE
```

---

Updated with benchmark:

```
library(microbenchmark)

f1 <- function(group.prevalence, population) {
  grouped.population <- array(NA, dim=c(2,2,2,3), 
                              dimnames=list(group=c("A","B"),
                                            age=c("young","old"),
                                            gender=c("male","female"),
                                            year=c("year1","year2","year3")))
  for (group in c("A","B")) {
    for(gender in c("male","female")) {
      for (age in c("young","old")) {
        grouped.population[group,age,gender,] <- group.prevalence[group,age,gender] * population[age,gender,]}}}
}

f2 <- function(group.prevalence, population) {
  grouped.population2 <- array(rep(group.prevalence, times=last(dim(population))) * 
                               rep(population, each=first(dim(group.prevalence))), 
                               dim=c(2,2,2,3), 
                               dimnames=list(group=c("A","B"),
                                             age=c("young","old"),
                                             gender=c("male","female"),
                                             year=c("year1","year2","year3")))
}

print(microbenchmark(f1(group.prevalence, population)))
##Unit: microseconds
##                             expr     min      lq     mean   median      uq     max neval
## f1(group.prevalence, population) 101.473 103.998 149.2562 106.8865 115.372 1185.32   100
print(microbenchmark(f2(group.prevalence, population)))
##Unit: microseconds
##                             expr    min     lq     mean median      uq     max neval
## f2(group.prevalence, population) 66.392 67.672 70.19873 68.454 69.4205 173.284   100
```

I believe the performance will diverge even more as the number of dimensions and the size in each dimension increases.

Comment: This isn't a bad idea but it is much slower than `for()` loop on my env.

Comment: @cuttlefish44: Wow, I did not know that. Should have profiled before posting. This is how one would do it in C/C++/Fortran except that we would not actually permute the dimensions, but just keep track of them internally. I would guess that that is the bottleneck here. Do you know of a package that does this in R?

Comment: @cuttlefish44: I was actually referring to a multi-dim array manipulation package for this problem.